# Using scroll wheels as mouse movement?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I got this [mouse](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/03/videogames/aplus/B00A72ZQLE/MCB437050001_rat_5_gw_A.jpg) and I want ask, if it's possible to use the two scroll wheels for cursor movement: the upper wheel for vertical movement and the bottom one for horizontal movement. I already tried the main software for the mouse but there wasn't such an option. I would be really glad if someone could help me out.